# Backbone js app structure

Tags: backbone.js

Currently am writing all my business logic inside the view class which make my view class unmanageable.  Am planning to create Backbone object and move all the business logic there and invoke it from view class. Please correct me with right way of thinking

Comment: You can use Backbone model for all the business logic. right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone in general does not provide an entity named Controller, this is one of the reasons which  Backbone called MV*. Generally user interact with views, you know well this interact means change and update over models.

"So does Backbone.js have controllers? Not really. Backbone’s views typically contain
controller logic, and routers are used to help manage application state, but neither are
true controllers according to classical MVC." ([Addy Osmani Book's](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/))

so i think your way is not incorrect, but you can improve your project structure through this solutions:

1. [Marrionette](http://marionettejs.com/) (and also [Thorax](http://thoraxjs.org/) ) is a excellent framework that provide such a excellent structure for your app. You can read this annotated code and get some tip from it.
2. You know certainly AMD a nice api to provide modular pattern in js. [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) a nice tool for organize your code. For more information i recommend check [TodoMVC + Backbone+Require](http://todomvc.com/examples/backbone_require/) code.

Comment: Not a superuser of backbone, but doesn't the Router provide a lot of the "controller-esque" functionality?